# Avoiding exploding indices and entity-group write-rate limits with appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing

I have an application in which there are `Course`s, `Topic`s, and `Tag`s.  Each `Topic` can be in many `Course`s and have many `Tag`s. I want to look up every `Topic` that has a specific `Tag` x and is in specific `Course` y.

1. Naively, I give each standard a list of `Course` ids and `Tag` ids, so I can `select * from Topic where tagIds = x && courseIds = y`.  I think this query would require an exploding index: with 30 courses and 30 tags we're looking at ~900 index entries, right?  At 50 x 20 I'm well over the 5000-entry limit.
2. I could just `select * from Topic where tagIds = x`, and then use a for loop to go through the result, choosing only `Topic`s whose `courseIds.contain(y)`.  This returns way more results than I'm interested in and spends a lot of time deserializing those results, but the index stays small.
3. I could `select __KEY__ from Topic where tagIds = x` AND `select __KEY__ from Topic where courseIds = y` and find the intersection in my application code.  If the sets are small this might not be unreasonable.
4. I could make a sort of join table, `TopicTagLookup` with a `tagId` and `courseId` field.  The parent key of these entities would point to the relevant `Topic`.  Then I would need to make one of these `TopicTagLookup` entities for every combination of courseId x tagId x relevant topic id.  This is effectively like creating my own index.  It would still explode, but there would be no 5000-entry limit.  Now, however, I need to write 5000 entities to the same entity group, which would run up against the entity-group write-rate limit!
5. I could precalculate each query.  A `TopicTagQueryCache` entity would hold a `tagId`, `courseId`, and a `List<TopicId>`.  Then the query looks like `select * from TopicTagQueryCache where tagId=x && courseId = y`, fetching the list of topic ids, and then using a `getAllById` call on the list.  Similar to #3, but I only have one entity per courseId x tagId.  There's no need for entity groups, but now I have this potentially huge list to maintain transactionally.

Appengine seems great for queries you can precalculate.  I just don't quite see a way to precalculate this query efficiently.  The question basically boils down to:

**What's the best way to organize data so that we can do set operations like finding the `Topic`s in the intersection of a `Course` and a `Tag`?**

Comment: Related question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093340/set-operations-in-appengine-datastore

Comment: unfortunately i was only able to give answers for the easy cases in that question - small sets or small numbers of sets :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assessment of your options is correct. If you don't need any sort criteria, though, option 3 is more or less already done for you by the App Engine datastore, with the merge join strategy. Simply do a query as you detail in option 1, without any sorts or inequality filters, and App Engine will do a merge join internally in the datastore, and return only the relevant results.

Options 4 and 5 are similar to the relation index pattern documented in [this talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html).

Comment: Whoa! Are you suggesting that option 1 would not have an exploding index after all, because all it needs is the index on courseIds and the index on tagIds, but not one on courseIds x tagIds?

Comment: I see from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgaL6NGpkB8 that Brett Slatkin basically says we don't need to build a special index for these ordinary equality filters.  This is fantastic news!

Comment: @Riley It won't have an exploding index if you don't define one. And you probably don't need one if you only use equality filters and no sort orders.

Answer (score 1):

I like #5 - you are essentially creating your own (exploding) index.  It will be fast to query.

The only downsides are that you have to manually maintain it (next paragraph), and retrieving the `Topic` entity will require an extra query (first you query `TopicTagQueryCache` to get the topic ID and then you need to actually retrieve the topic).

Updating the `TopicTagQueryCache` you suggested shouldn't be a problem either.   I wouldn't worry about doing it transactionally - this "index" will just be stale for a short period of time when you update a `Topic` (at worst, your `Topic` will temporarily show up in results it should no longer show up in, and perhaps take a moment before it shows up in new results which it should show up it - this doesn't seem so bad).  You can even do this update on the task queue (to make sure this potentially large number of database writes all succeed, and so that you can quickly finish the request so your user isn't waiting).

Answer (score 0):

As you said yourself you should arrange your data  to facilitate the scaling of your app, thus in the question of **What's the best way to organize data so that we can do set operations like finding the Topics in the intersection of a Course and a Tag?**

You can hold your own indexes of these sets by creating objects of CourseRef and TopicRef which consist of Key only, with the ID portion being an actual Key of the corresponding entity. These "Ref" entities will be under a specific tag, thus no actual Key duplicates. So the structure for a given Tag is : *Tag\CourseRef...\TopicRef...*

This way given a Tag and Course, you construct the Key Tag\CourseRef and do an [ancestor Query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html) which gets you a set of keys you can fetch. This is extremely fast as it is actually a direct access, and this should handle large lists of courses or topics without the issues of List properties.

**This method will require you to use the DataStore API to some extent.** 
As you can see this gives answer to a specific question, and the model will do no good for other type of Set operations.